# Notification from Android APK Expansion automatic update

Tags: android, download, google-play, updates, apk-expansion-files

I followed this guide and implemented APK Expansions, using the provided Downloader Library, and everything works perfectly:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Now I would like to update my app, and the expansion files as well. I uploaded a new APK and new expansion files to Google Play. After the update is successful, I have the new .obb files in the proper directory: Android/obb/package-name .

The problem is that I need to unzip a certain file from the new .obb after the update, the app cannot function without this new file. But because Google Play does the update, my app does not get notified that the .obb was updated, and that it should unzip this certain file.

Is there any way or best practice to make my app aware that it was updated, and the expansion files were replaced by Google Play? (I support API 10+.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this wasn't so hard:

I used a flag in SharedPreferences which is different for every application version. If it is false then the file is unzipped from the .obb, and the flag is set to true. So the file is unzipped after each update.